# Django 1.5 Custom User Model unknown column

Tags: django, django-authentication

I am using Django 1.5s Custom User Model. I want to let a user type their username in - and be logged in. NO PASSWORD (for testing anyway). My User Model doesnt have a password. But when i try to login to admin I get the following error:

```
OperationalError(1054, "Unknown column 'hrms.password' in 'field list'"
```

It seems to be trying to execute this query in the authenticate() method.

```
SELECT `myusers`.`password`, `myusers`.`last_login`, `myusers`.`id`, `myusers`.`user`, `myusers`.`name`, `myusers`.`firstname`, `myusers`.`lastname`, `myusers`.`organisation`, `myusers`.`unit`, `myusers`.`grade`, `myusers`.`email`, `myusers`.`position`, `myusers`.`manager` FROM `myusers` WHERE `myusers`.`user` = 'warrenm' "
```

I do not have the fields password, last_login - I dont know why its trying to get them.

Below is my code.

**My Backend (auth.py)**

```
from epmds.application.models import AuthUser

class MyBackend(object):

    def get_user(self, user_id):
        # get a user from the user_id
        try:
            return AuthUser.objects.get(pk=user_id)
        except AuthUser.DoesNotExist:
            return None

    def authenticate(self, username=None, password=None):
        # check the username/password and return a user
        user = AuthUser.objects.get(user=username)
        return user
```

**MY Model**

```
class AuthUser(AbstractBaseUser):
    id = models.CharField(primary_key=True, max_length=15)
    user = models.CharField('username', max_length=20, unique=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    firstname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    lastname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    organisation = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    email = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)

    USERNAME_FIELD = 'user'

    def get_full_name(self):
        full_name = '%s %s' % (self.first_name, self.last_name)
        return full_name.strip()

    def get_short_name(self):
        return self.first_name

    class Meta:
        ordering = ('lastname', 'firstname')
        managed = False
        db_table = 'myusers'
```

Comment: `password` is part of `AbstractBaseUser` so it should be automatically added in your `AuthUser`. Have you done `syncdb` successfully?

Comment: yes, but I have managed = False in the meta as I dont want Django to manage it. The users are managed externally.

Comment: I believe you will have to add that field in the db table then.

Comment: ye you're right - added it and it seems to be fine!

Answer (score 0):

`password` is part of `AbstractBaseUser` so it should be added in your `AuthUser` model as well in table.

As you have `managed=False` for this model, you need to add that explicitly.